# Joining Pandas dataframes in Python with the same index multiple times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
>>>import import pandas as pd
>>>df1:

                 DD_PRICE
DATE                         
2013-09-19 20:55:00  3.516
2013-09-19 20:55:00  3.516
2013-09-19 20:55:00  3.516
2013-09-19 20:55:00 -4.476

>>>df2:
                 CAPI_PRICE
DATE                         
2013-09-19 20:55:00  3.516
2013-09-19 20:55:00  3.516
2013-09-19 20:55:00  3.516
2013-09-19 20:55:00 -4.476
```

Now when I run:

```
 joint_df = df1.join((df2), how='outer')
```

`joint_df` looks like this:

```
                  DD_PRICE  CAPI_PRICE
DATE                                   
2013-09-19 20:55:00  3.516  3.516
2013-09-19 20:55:00  3.516  3.516
2013-09-19 20:55:00  3.516  3.516
2013-09-19 20:55:00  3.516 -4.476
2013-09-19 20:55:00  3.516  3.516
2013-09-19 20:55:00  3.516  3.516
2013-09-19 20:55:00  3.516  3.516
2013-09-19 20:55:00  3.516 -4.476
2013-09-19 20:55:00  3.516  3.516
2013-09-19 20:55:00  3.516  3.516
2013-09-19 20:55:00  3.516  3.516
2013-09-19 20:55:00  3.516 -4.476
2013-09-19 20:55:00 -4.476  3.516
2013-09-19 20:55:00 -4.476  3.516
2013-09-19 20:55:00 -4.476  3.516
2013-09-19 20:55:00 -4.476 -4.476
```

This isnt what I want...

Ideally I want `joint_df` to look like this:

```
                  DD_PRICE  CAPI_PRICE
DATE                                   
2013-09-19 20:55:00  3.516  3.516
2013-09-19 20:55:00  3.516  3.516
2013-09-19 20:55:00  3.516  3.516
2013-09-19 20:55:00 -4.476 -4.476
```

How do I get this done? Tried different combos of `merge` and `join` parameters but I can't get it to work!

Comment: You have duplicate index. If the order of index in both dataframes always same, use `df1['CAPI_PRICE'] = df2['CAPI_PRICE'].values`?

Comment: `df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)` does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) only - by default there is outer join:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
print (df)
                     DD_PRICE  CAPI_PRICE
DATE                                     
2013-09-19 20:55:00     3.516       3.516
2013-09-19 20:55:00     3.516       3.516
2013-09-19 20:55:00     3.516       3.516
2013-09-19 20:55:00    -4.476      -4.476
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to just add a new column on first data frame by copying it from second data frame like this:

```
df1['CAPI_PRICE']=df2['CAPI_PRICE']
```